# DynamicProperties in Spring Data Neo4j 4 does not support any workaround

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

`Spring neo4j-4` does not support `DynamicProperties`.

Is there any workaround for this in `SDN4`?

Answer (score 0):

Not at the moment. It's on the roadmap though (release unknown).

You can of course write a converter to serialize a map of properties as a String (JSON for example), but that means all your dynamic properties are squashed into a String and you stuff such as @Query or derived finders won't work.